# Variable isn't declaring inside of my function?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I created the variable `'game_window'` inside of the function `'lib_window'` but the console keeps saying the local variable `'game_window'` value is not used. I have no idea what that means. My goal is to simply link a new window with the `'start_Btn'`. I even have `'command=lib_window()'` in the midst of things.

```
import tkinter as tk

class windowLib:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('700x500')
        self.root.title('UnLibs')
        self.root['background'] = '#91a8e3'
        self.start_Btn = tk.Button(self.root,
                                   command=lib_window(),
                                   text="PLAY",
                                   foreground="white",
                                   highlightbackground="red",
                                   font=("Helvetica", 40))
        self.welcome_Label = tk.Label(self.root,
                                      text="Welcome to UnLibs",
                                      font=("Helvetica", 50),
                                      bg="#91a8e3",
                                      fg="white")
        self.start_Btn.pack(side="bottom", padx=10, pady=50)
        self.welcome_Label.pack(side="top", padx=0, pady=150)
        self.root.mainloop()

def lib_window():
   
    game_window = tk.Toplevel(windowLib)

windowLib()
```

Answer (score 0):

It says it is not used because you are declaring a variable (In this case, game_window) and not using it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

> but the console keeps saying the local variable `game_window` value is
> not used.

- Move the `lib_window` method inside `init()` function. Add `self` in
  `lib_window` function parameter.
- Add `self` in keyword `command=`.

Run the script.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

class windowLib:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('700x500')
        self.root.title('UnLibs')
        self.root['background'] = '#91a8e3'
        self.start_Btn = tk.Button(self.root,
                                   command=self.lib_window,
                                   text="PLAY",
                                   foreground="white",
                                   highlightbackground="red",
                                   font=("Helvetica", 40))
        
        self.welcome_Label = tk.Label(self.root,
                                      text="Welcome to UnLibs",
                                      font=("Helvetica", 50),
                                      bg="#91a8e3",
                                      fg="white")
        self.start_Btn.pack(side="bottom", padx=10, pady=50)
        self.welcome_Label.pack(side="top", padx=0, pady=15)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def lib_window(self):
       
        game_window = tk.Toplevel()

if __name__=='__main__':

    windowLib()
```

Screenshot for main and `Toplevel`:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i think that what are you searching for:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Toplevel


def lib_window():
game_window = tk.Toplevel (windowLib)

windowLib ()


class windowLib:

def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk ()
    self.root.geometry ('700x500')
    self.root.title ('UnLibs')
    self.root['background'] = '#91a8e3'
    self.start_Btn = tk.Button (self.root,
                                command=lib_window (),
                                text="PLAY",
                                foreground="white",
                                highlightbackground="red",
                                font=("Helvetica", 40))
    self.welcome_Label = tk.Label (self.root,
                                   text="Welcome to UnLibs",
                                   font=("Helvetica", 50),
                                   bg="#91a8e3",
                                   fg="white")
    self.start_Btn.pack (side="bottom", padx=10, pady=50)
    self.welcome_Label.pack (side="top", padx=0, pady=150)
    self.root.mainloop ()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter as tk

class windowLib:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('700x500')
        self.root.title('UnLibs')
        self.root['background'] = '#91a8e3'
        self.start_Btn = tk.Button(self.root,
                                   command=lib_window(),
                                   text="PLAY",
                                   foreground="white",
                                   highlightbackground="red",
                                   font=("Helvetica", 40))
        self.welcome_Label = tk.Label(self.root,
                                      text="Welcome to UnLibs",
                                      font=("Helvetica", 50),
                                      bg="#91a8e3",
                                      fg="white")
        self.start_Btn.pack(side="bottom", padx=10, pady=50)
        self.welcome_Label.pack(side="top", padx=0, pady=150)
        self.root.mainloop()

        game_window = tk.Toplevel(windowLib)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    windowLib()
```

This may work....

Comment: IMHO, it will be better to add an explanation on what was wrong and why.